# Keep alive multiple boto s3 connections

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently using flask+docker for deploying a model which require AWS s3 connection (for downloading files). Now as per my understanding, the latency of the service will be in three parts:

1. Time taken for setting up the s3 connection.
2. Downloading the files into docker image using that s3 connection (Since it will deployed in ec2 instance only, so the time taken will be low.)
3. Using the model (We can optimise it in some way (maybe use lighter models))

For the 1st one, can we save the time for setting up the s3 connection? As in keep a pool of active sessions which can be used whenever i get any request to my service. If yes what is the best way to go for it?

Comment: My advice: don't optimize for speed right now. Get the main application working first.

Comment: @flakes I agree what you just said and that can be done by using lighter models for getting the predictions. But my concern was to optimise for the time taken for setting up the s3 connection by keeping a pool of active connections so that 1st point latency can be minimised.